# How to Encapsulate 3rd Party Plugin Logic in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working on an Angular 2 project, powered by the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

I need to integrate a 3rd party plugin. I am wondering which is the best approach to **encapsulate as much plugin-related logic as possible in one place**.

---

I will illustrate the issue with my use-case: I need to implement this notification plugin: https://github.com/akserg/ng2-toasty

I decided to encapsulate plugin-related initialization and configuration logic in a *service*, so I use my `NotificationService` abstraction across my project. I do this mainly because in case I need to change or replace the library with another one, ideally, I want to end up with only one place where I need to do the changes.

Here's my `notification.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastyService, ToastyConfig, ToastOptions } from 'ng2-toasty';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

    constructor(
        private toastyService:  ToastyService,
        private toastyConfig: ToastyConfig
    ) {
        this.toastyConfig.theme = 'bootstrap';
    }

    fireSuccess(msg: string, title: string = 'Success!') {
        const toastOptions: ToastOptions = {
            title,
            msg
        };

        this.toastyService.success(toastOptions);
    }

}
```

However, the plugin-related logic is spread across 3 more places (files):

1. Plugin's stylesheet is imported in the `angular-cli.json`:

   ```
   {
       "apps": [
           ... // omitted for brevity
           {
             "styles": [
               "styles.scss",
               "../node_modules/ng2-toasty/style-bootstrap.css"
             ],
           }
       ],
       ... // omitted for brevity
   }
   ```
2. Plugin's import - `ToastyModule.forRoot()` is placed in my app `NgModule`:

   ```
   import { ToastyModule } from 'ng2-toasty';

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           ToastyModule.forRoot()
       ],
       ... // omitted for brevity
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
3. Plugin's `<ng2-toasty></ng2-toasty>` tag should be placed somewhere in any template in my app ([that's a plugin-related requirement](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-toasty#1-update-the-markup)). So I added the tag in my main `app.component.html`.

The thing that bothers me is that the plugin-related logic is spread across a total of 4 files: `notification.service`, `angular-cli.json`, `app.module.ts` and `app.component.html`.

---

This is the most encapsulated approach that I could think of. I wonder if there a way I move more of the plugin-related logic in a single place (maybe in the `notification.service`).

So, to sum-up my question:

> Is this the best approach to encapsulate and abstract 3rd party plugin in Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `<ng2-toasty></ng2-toasty>` is a component (correct me if it's not). Therefore you can encapsulate the css (scss as well) related to this in `@Component` decorator using ( `style` | `styleUrls` ) field just like described in [angular 2 component styling guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html). This is the best way to encapsulate styles.

Encapsulating your plugin's logic in an injectable is a good idea, because, obviously you'll need to inject that object into classes that require it.

But injectable doesn't always mean service. In angular 2 [service concept](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) means an object that provides an interface to fetch and save data from a data source. Using services makes your app easy to test since you can mock the service object and provide your components with fake data.

Considering this I would rename `NotificationService` to something else. Maybe `Notifier` or something else to not confuse it with service it's up to you.

But generally there's some good software design here, just need to work with concepts.

Comment: Yes, I was having troubles with the concept and if my general approach is correct. Based on what you've said: 1) I will rename the `NotificationService` to `Notifier`. 2) I will create a Notifier component where I will list the plugin styles and the `<ng2-toasty></ng2-toasty>` tag. This way there will be 1 less file to work with (`angular-cli.json`). That's great! Last question: is there any way I escape from the import in the `@NgModule` and do the import maybe in the Notifier component somehow?

Comment: @KaloyanKosev No, I believe there is no way to get rid of `@NgModule` import, but generally it's not even a problem. Since `Notifier` is an app-scoped module it should be imported in the app module.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, the `Notifier` import sounds just fine. I was actually referring to the `ToastyModule.forRoot()` import in the `@NgModule`. I wonder if I can get rid of it somehow, like import it somehow inside the `Notifier` maybe?

Comment: @KaloyanKosev Yes, I did understand that you mean `ToastyModule.forRoot()` import. This is just how angular encapsulation works. If you encapsulate something into a module you need to import it. It looks like `ToastyModule` "contains" `Notifier`, and exports it, taking this into account I don't see a way in which you can import `ToastyModule` inside `Notifier`.

Comment: All right, Arkadii, I understand. Thank you very much! :-)